# Spring MVC 400 Bad Request when fields are empty

Tags: spring-mvc

I am getting 400 Bad request when I perform AJAX post if the form fields are empty. However when I key in any values to the field then I submit the request the server is able to process it.

I attached screenshots for both cases (success and fail)

[image]
[image]

Is this normal ?

**The Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/setsponsor", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ValidationResponse updateSponsorTab(@Valid SetSponsorBO setSponsorBO, Locale locale,BindingResult result) {

        ValidationResponse res = new ValidationResponse();
        List<ErrorMessage> errorMesages = new ArrayList<ErrorMessage>();
        if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            res.setStatus(messageSource.getMessage("success.message", null, locale));
            try{
                res.setValue(myAccountService.updateSponsor(setSponsorBO));
                if(!res.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(messageSource.getMessage("success.message", null, locale))){
                    res.setStatus("FAIL");  
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("Error AccountController set sponsor : " + ex.getMessage());
                res.setValue(messageSource.getMessage("failed.message", null, locale));
                res.setStatus("FAIL");
            }
        } else {
            res.setStatus("FAIL");
            List<FieldError> allErrors = result.getFieldErrors();
            for (FieldError objectError : allErrors) {
                errorMesages.add(new ErrorMessage(objectError.getField(),
                        objectError.getDefaultMessage()));
            }
            res.setValue(messageSource.getMessage("failed.message", null, locale));         
        }
        res.setErrorMessageList(errorMesages);

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: That depends how you're putting data to the server. If there's something like this: `data: { sponsorUsername:'', securityPassword:'' } `, wont have problems... But, what I think it's going on: `data: { sponsorUsername: securityPassword: }` , or something like that... This way, `sponsorUsername` will have value `securityPassword`, but the `securityPassword` variable will not exists...

Comment: Seeing the controller, it may be the `@Valid` annotation... Which validations `SetSponsorBO` have for these parameters?

Comment: @NotBlank and @Length(max=100) for both fields

Comment: Probably if you remove `@NotBlank` it will work. Maybe in this case you have to check if it's blank inside the method.

Comment: You're right with removing @NotBlank. But why is this behaving this way?

Comment: Your method expects a valid SetSponsorBO. When you dont have one, your request is not valid. BANG. Bad request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably if you remove `@NotBlank` it will work. Maybe in this case you have to check if it's blank inside the method. Your method expects a valid `SetSponsorBO` . When you don't have one, your request is not valid. Bad request.